# HTML Nested Tables data cut off of second table

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested

I have a html structure like this, and the purpose is to have a CSS overflow: scroll when the media query is for a mobile device (Data is not long enough but it works):

```
<TABLE BORDER=0>
   <TR>
      <TD>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>x</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </TD>
      <TD>
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>x</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
                  <td>xyyy</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
```

When I try to resize on a small screen, the second table is simply just being cut off. I tried to set the overall width of the table to 100% and removed the max-width, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

What should the table  display?

Comment: can you give a screen-shot of your problem?

Comment: @Jesse I have attached screenshots to the post

Comment: did you set `overflow: auto` to the father element of the table?